# Can I have a multi-lingual navigation when using PyroCMS?

Tags: php, navigation, multilingual, pyrocms

I'm running version 1.3.2 which was until very recently the most recent version. I don't know if this has changed in 2.0.0 but I won't be upgrading my project anyway so it doesn't really matter.

I'd like to have a multilingual navigation but the only field I have for the link is `Title`. Does PyroCMS offer support for this?

[image: Navigation Options]

Comment: If you would just do a search and then try out what you find, you might find out if you can or not have that. But as long as you did not, it's hardly a question to be answered here.

Comment: In case it helps: https://github.com/sazan/MultiLang-Library-for-PyroCMS

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience in 1.3, but you might want to search it in your group attribute..

Just create a group for each language and do something like this with the Lex tags (example based on 2.0 version tag conditionals):

```
{{ if {lang:name} == 'Dutch' }}
  {{ navigation:links group="dutch_header" }}
{{ elseif {lang:name} == 'German' }}
  {{ navigation:links group="german_header" }}
{{ elseif {lang:name} == 'Spanish' }}
  {{ navigation:links group="spanish_header" }}
{{ else }}
  {{ navigation:links group="english_header" }}
{{ endif }}
```

Now in the admin -> design navigationpage add navigation groups named "dutch_header", "german_header", "spanish_header" and "english_header".

Now just add a navigation menu to all four of the groups and each language has its own navigation.

I hope this is what you were looking for ;) GL